# VBA: Add Suffix to Duplicate Value within Column

Tags: vba, duplicates, range, suffix

I hope you can help me resolving an issue in VBA with regard to adding a suffix to duplicate values. I have a range that looks like the following:

```
COL A:
000049
000050
000051
000052 (duplicate)
000052 (duplicate)
000053
000054
```

What I want to achieve is that once there is a duplicate in Column A, it adds a suffix to **both** numbers. I've only managed (using a loop) to set it for one of the fields.

Conditions:

1. If there is a duplicate, all duplicates must have a suffix;
2. If there is a new duplicate (let say we have 000052A and 000052B and we now move to 000061), the suffix count has to restart back from A.

Your help is really much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you show said code please,

Comment: You haven't described how the suffix should look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this with a formula:

```
=A1 & IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1, MID("ABCDEFGHIJK", COUNTIF($A$1:A1, A1), 1),"")
```

And copy down.

That says "Grab the value from A1 and if there is a duplicate anywhere in column A then go and get the character from string "ABCDEFGHIJK" that corresponds to how many times this value has appeared already in the list (from A1 to whatever row we are on)"

Comment: Hi JNevill,

You certainly make me scratch my head twice, as it's indeed much simpler with the formula than to do it with a VBA loop. Thanks a lot for the help here, this will do!