# Adding a suffix to duplicates in excel

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, numbers, suffix

I'm looking for some clarification to an answer that was found at the link below.
[Rename duplicates with random alphabets in a column - Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044496/rename-duplicates-with-random-alphabets-in-a-column-excel)

The example shows how to add a prefix to duplicates in excel. How do I add a suffix rather than a prefix? I also want to use numbers instead of letters, and I've figured out how to add numbers 1-9, but some duplicates go higher than that, is it possible to number higher than 1-9?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please review @JNevill answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158120/vba-add-suffix-to-duplicate-value-within-column)

Comment: Although this solution is similar, I was looking for something that wouldn't require having to make my own string. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula (Assuming data in column A and there is a header)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A2)>0,A2 & "." & COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A2),A2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the solution works great. I am wondering, is there a way to start the labeling on the first instance of a duplicate, rather than the second?

Comment: You're welcome. Try this
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A2)>=0,A2 & "." & COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A2)+1,A2)

Comment: Perfect, I appreciate the help!